# Oracle Timestamp precision not obeyed

Tags: database, oracle, timestamp

I created a table in Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE clock
(
Year TIMESTAMP(3)
);
```

I inserted a value and hope that it will be stored with 3 decimal digits precision.

```
insert
into clock (Year)
values ( TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000');
commit;
```

However when i run a select query it gives output with 9 decimal precison

```
select * from clock;
```

Output:

01-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM

Expected output

01-JAN-14 12.00.00.000 AM

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being *stored* with three decimal digits precision, it's just not being *displayed* with 3 digits precision, presumably because of your database's NLS settings.

If you insert a number with more than 3 digits' precision, the extra digits get truncated.  For example, try running

```
insert into clock (Year) values (TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 12:34:56.123456789');
```

Then

```
select * from clock;
```

should return

```
01-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM
01-JAN-14 12.34.56.123000000 PM
```

If you don't want to show the extra digits, then try something like the following instead:

```
select to_char(Year, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF3 AM') from clock;
```

Comment: Thanks Luke.. i can now understand what is happening. Indeed the data is getting stored upto 3 precision digits only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your default TIMESTAMP format.
Try this then is should work.

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SSXFF3 AM';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I would not want to change the NLS setting. I can change my select query ( which I had already done) to get the output in the format I want. Luke's reply told me exactly what was happening :)